# 3s 25p li-ion battery pack charging parameters

Tags: lithium-ion

I'm having a LG HG2 18650 3s 25p battery pack.To charge the pack i planned to use EPEVER mppt charger controller. But for that  i have to set the Float charging voltage,boost charging voltage and equalization charging voltage.Can anyone suggest the parameter values?

Comment: Yes, the battery manufacturer can.

Comment: The degree of cell mismatch depends on age and SoC which may benefit from a balancer to extend life.  Meanwhile the charge profile for each cell can be multiplied by the array size, but perhaps a more conservative cutoff current.  E.g.  cutoff of 10% CC in CV mode is more conservative than 3 to 5% CC.  The CC charge rate depends on the self heating due to ESR and thus C rate of the cell.  Safe charge level is 1C = CC charge rate =20h,  while up to 40C charge rate requires a highest quality low ESR cell.   Always consult specs and match each 3S string for Voc and mA capacity.